# shiny app docker container failed to launch in browser

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I'm trying to run my shiny app in a docker container. 
My app folder structure is like this:

```
myApp (directory)
    -app (directory)
        --ui.R
        --server.R
        --global.R
        --style.css
        --mydata.xlsx
        --mydata2.rds
        --functions.R (contains functions I use in app)
    -Dockerfile
    -shiny-server.conf
    -shiny-server.sh
```

I can get into my directory `myApp` and run shiny locally by doing `runApp('app')`. my shiny app runs perfectly.

However, when I try to build the image and run it,  it give me error.

```
docker build -t myshinyapp_obs .
docker run -p 80:80 myshinyapp_obs 

The application failed to start.
The application exited during initialization.
```

The docker image building process seems to be fine. 
When run it on docker, I got error.

The interesting thing is when I simply copy any app from shiny gallery and put the `ui.R` and `server.R` file under the app folder, it works fine!!!

My question is why my app is not working? given the fact:

1. my app work perfectly locally
2. After copying shiny example from gallery into the app folder,  the example app works fine.

How can that happen? I cannot figure it out. Spent hours trying to make it work but failed.

Below is my Dockfile:

```
# Install R version 3.6
FROM r-base:3.6.0

# Install Ubuntu packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    gdebi-core \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev/unstable \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev

# Download and install ShinyServer (latest version)
RUN wget --no-verbose https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/VERSION -O "version.txt" && \
    VERSION=$(cat version.txt)  && \
    wget --no-verbose "https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-shiny-server-os-build/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-$VERSION-amd64.deb" -O ss-latest.deb && \
    gdebi -n ss-latest.deb && \
    rm -f version.txt ss-latest.deb

# Install R packages that are required
# TODO: add further package if you need!
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('devtools','readxl','tidyverse','rlang','shiny','shinythemes', 'DT'), repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
COPY /app /srv/shiny-server/

# Make the ShinyApp available at port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here to know why your app is failing to start, but usually when I see that message it means that I have failed to include all the right packages or system dependencies. FWIW, you may want to have a look at the rocker/shiny image.

Comment: @edavidaja   thanks a lot. I will double check if I have all the packages.

Comment: You should add some logging which will make the error clear. Install `xtail` in your `apt-get install` and edit your `shiny-server.sh` file: https://github.com/rocker-org/shiny/issues/44